# How do I get a content type's parent name via powershell?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, content-type

I am attempting to write a powershell script to pull content type names applied to lists, and their respective parent content type name.  Unfortunately, I seem to have run into a hurdle - whenever I attempt to pull "$contenttype.Parent.Name" it returns the name of the content type I am currently querying - not its parent content type name.

Reading online, I see many examples which work with GUID's but I do not need something so precise or complex - I only want the name of the parent for the current content type.

The following is the relevant code I am working with:

```
  foreach ($listct in $list.ContentTypes)
  {
    $ctname = $listct.name
    $ctgroup = $listct.Group
    $ctparent = $listct.Parent.Name
  }
```

How can I grab the Parent Content type's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are hitting is that SharePoint, when a content type is associated with a specific lists, adds an extra GUID to the Content Type ID.

This makes it a child content type if the original one, even if it theoretically is not.

You should be able to get the correct parent content type by doing something like:

```
$listct.Parent.Parent.Name
```

Comment: Glad it worked! It is a bit of a culprit that it works that way when assigning a content type to a list (but I guess SP wants to keep them unique for a good reason)

Comment: Worked - awesome. I forgot that parent of inherited was always the same. Thanks for the quick reminder.